# Sencha Touch 2- Parsing Store JSON file containing Array

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I have the following JSON file I would like to parse into my Sencha Touch application. I cannot figure out what type of "store" (Store, JsonStore, ArrayStore, etc.) to use and what the "field" setup would be like. Each "datapoint" in the array should be stored as an xValue and a yValue. I don't understand how these points can be read without individual tags

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_text": "Success",
  "data": [
    "Ajwan",
    "Alasande Gram",
    "All Flower",
    ...
    "Wood",
    "Wool",
    "Yam",
    "Yam (Ratalu)"
  ],
  "count": 357
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have already answered a bit early at the other question you have to use a JsonStore with your customized Reader.

in your version of Reader you have to override  readRecords: function(data) {} method...

Cheers, Oleg